# Powershell script compares file at remote path with Local Path and copies it to Local Path if new

Tags: powershell, scripting

I want to create a Powershell script that connects to a Network Drive and then compares the file on the remote with the local file. If the file on remote destination(on the shared Drive) is newer then it copies it to the local destination.

Below is the code i used.

```
net use Y:

if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)

{
    net use Y: Path
}

$folders = @{local = 'Local Path';remote='Remote Path'},

$folders | Foreach {xcopy $_.remote $_.local /S /C /Y /D /I}
```

I get the following OutPut

```
Local Name Y:
Remote Name \\Path of the shared drive
Resource Type Disk
The command Completed Sucessfully

File Not Found

Invalid Number of Parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `$folders` is not an array, why Foreach? Why not just

```
$folders = @{local = 'Local Path';remote='Remote Path'},
xcopy $folders.remote $folders.local /S /C /Y /D /I
```

Or is the actual code different from the example?